# Spring Boot passing JSON and simple attributes to the same mapping

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm new in Spring Boot and I want to have the same Request Mapping method for JSON and simple request params, for example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/start")
public String startPostProcess(@RequestParam(value = "url",
                                    required = false,
                                    defaultValue = "https://goo.gl") String url,
                               @RequestParam(value = "word",
                                    required = false,
                                    defaultValue = "Search") String word,
                               @RequestBody String hereGoesJSON) {
             //Do some stuff
        }
```

So, when request goes with params, only @RequestParam will work, in other cases we will use @RequestBody annotation.

```
localhost:8080/start?url=htts://google.com&word=Luck
```

Or may bee I'll be able to write method like this, for accepting any params:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/start")
    public String startPostProcess(@RequestBody String anyParam) {
//Parse this anyParam
}
```

?

I've not found this trick in spring documentation, so I will appreciate any links to it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've solved the problem :D

All that I just needed was 2 methods with the same mapping and explicitly specify RequestMethod type:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/start")
public String startPostProcess(@RequestParam(value = "url",
                                    required = false,
                                    defaultValue = "https://goo.gl") String url,
                               @RequestParam(value = "word",
                                    required = false,
                                    defaultValue = "Search") String word) throws InterruptedException {

    //Do some stuff
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/start", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public String startJsonProcess(@RequestBody String body) {
   //Do another stuff with RequestBody
}
```

UPD: added "consumes = "application/json". It helps dividing simple POST requests and JSON POST requests.